# Giving Virtual Machines in Xen their own IP Addresses

Tags: ip-address, virtual-machines, xen

Installed Xen on a server at home, recently moved it to a data center. Worked fine with DHCP behind my router, with each virtual server and the dom0 getting its own IP address.

At the data center, there's plenty of IP addresses to use, but they all need to be static. I managed to get the dom0 setup with a static IP like this, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 204.45.15.42
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 204.45.15.41
```

Comment: Basically do more of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure every virtual machine's static IP in

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

To pass the proper IP to your VM when creating one, add to your xen-create-image command this option :

```
root@nikita:~# xen-create-image --hostname <HOST> --ip <IP>
```

Comment: As in, use the same configuration, but in the /etc/network/interface file of each VM individually?

Thanks!

Comment: well that depends how you have set up your network in Xen, but normally it is a bridge, so yea, the only thing you will need to change are the IP addresses

Comment: Is there any additional configuration needed for the bridge? Or does Xen magically detect things like that?

Comment: yes and no, it is not magical, it is called a script :p : http://www.sparksupport.com/blog/xen-bridging

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/xen/xen-tools.conf
you should comment to get the following:

```
# dhcp = 1
```

I also use to mention my bridge in /etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf

```
 bridge=xenbr0
```

this bridge name will be the name of the bridge from /etc/network/interfaces

then uncomment the following:

```
gateway    = 192.168.1.1
netmask    = 255.255.255.0
broadcast  = 192.168.1.255
```

For namerservers, if you don't touch anything, the virtual machine will inherit from the Dom0 namerservers.

then when you create a Xen virtual machine, mention the Ip:

```
>xen-create-image --hostname=test105 --ip=192.168.1.105
```

From my own experience, i think it is better to put as many parameters as you can in xen-tools to keep the number of parameters to the smallest when you create a new virtual machine.